# Problema com redimensionamento de imagens PNG no PHP

Tags: php, imagem, gd

Boa noite.

Eu estou com um script de uma loja virtual aqui, mas estou tendo problemas com imagens em PNG.

Ao fazer o upload de uma imagem como essa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
.

O script verifica a extensão com base no mimetype, "sanitiza" o nome do arquivo e após tudo isso, gera 3 tamanhos dessa imagem, sendo eles Padrão, Miniatura e Zoom. Sendo que nas imagens "Padrão" e "Miniatura" ele faz o redimensionamento e no Zoom, se a imagem for grande o suficiente ele mantem o mesmo tamanho.

O problema é que quando ele redimensiona para um tamanho menor, a imagem fica meio que "quebrada":

[image: Imagem do tamanho "Padrão"]

E na miniatura fica pior ainda. Como eu posso fazer para deixar essa imagem mais lisa?

O script de upload e tratamento dessa imagem é meio complexo, então irei postar aqui os trechos que eu acho que são os principais.

O script abaixo faz o upload da imagem:

```
public static function importImage($temporaryPath, $originalFilename, $productId, $hash = false, $moveTemporaryFile = true, $generateImages = true)
{
    if (!file_exists($temporaryPath)) {
        throw new ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SOURCEFILEDOESNTEXIST_EXCEPTION($temporaryPath);
    }

    try {
        $library = ISC_IMAGE_LIBRARY_FACTORY::getImageLibraryInstance($temporaryPath);
    } catch (ISC_IMAGE_LIBRARY_FACTORY_INVALIDIMAGEFILE_EXCEPTION $ex) {
        throw new ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_IMPORT_INVALIDIMAGEFILE_EXCEPTION();
    } catch (ISC_IMAGE_LIBRARY_FACTORY_NOPHPSUPPORT_EXCEPTION $ex) {
        throw new ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_IMPORT_NOPHPSUPPORT_EXCEPTION();
    }

    if ($library->getWidth() < 1 || $library->getHeight() < 1) {
        throw new ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_IMPORT_EMPTYIMAGE_EXCEPTION();
    }

    $finalName = $originalFilename;


    $finalName = basename($finalName); // remove any path components from the filename
    $finalName = self::sanitiseFilename($finalName);

    if (!self::isValidFilename($finalName, false)) {
        throw new ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_IMPORT_INVALIDFILENAME_EXCEPTION($finalName);
    }

    // correct the uploaded extension
    $correctExtension = $library->getImageTypeExtension(false);
    if (strtolower(pathinfo($finalName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) != $correctExtension) {
        // remove existing extension and trailing . if any
        $finalName = preg_replace('#\.[^\.]*$#', '', $finalName);
        // add correct extension
        $finalName .= '.' . $correctExtension;
    }

    // generate a path for storing in the product_images directory
    $finalRelativePath = self::generateSourceImageRelativeFilePath($finalName);

    $image = new ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE();
    $image->setSourceFilePath($finalRelativePath);

    $finalAbsolutePath = $image->getAbsoluteSourceFilePath();
    $finalDirectory = dirname($finalAbsolutePath);

    if (!file_exists($finalDirectory)) {
        if (!isc_mkdir($finalDirectory, ISC_WRITEABLE_DIR_PERM, true)) {
            throw new ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_IMPORT_CANTCREATEDIR_EXCEPTION($finalDirectory);
        }
    }

    if ($moveTemporaryFile) {
        if (!@rename($temporaryPath, $finalAbsolutePath)) {
            throw new ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_IMPORT_CANTMOVEFILE_EXCEPTION($finalAbsolutePath);
        }
    } else {
        if (!@copy($temporaryPath, $finalAbsolutePath)) {
            throw new ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_IMPORT_CANTMOVEFILE_EXCEPTION($finalAbsolutePath);
        }
    }

    // check to see if the uploaded image exceeds our internal maximum image size: ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_MAXLONGEDGE
    if ($library->getWidth() > ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_MAXLONGEDGE || $library->getHeight() > ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_MAXLONGEDGE) {
        // if it is, resize it and overwrite the uploaded source image because we only want to store images to a maximum size of ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_MAXLONGEDGE x ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_MAXLONGEDGE
        $library->setFilePath($finalAbsolutePath);
        $library->loadImageFileToScratch();
        $library->resampleScratchToMaximumDimensions(ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_MAXLONGEDGE, ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_MAXLONGEDGE);
        $library->saveScratchToFile($finalAbsolutePath, self::getWriteOptionsForImageType($library->getImageType()));
    }

    if ($productId === false) {
        // do not assign product hash, id or save to database if $productId is false
        if ($generateImages) {
            // manually generate images since, normally, a call to saveToDatabase would do it
            $image->getResizedFileDimensions(ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SIZE_TINY, true, false);
            $image->getResizedFileDimensions(ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SIZE_THUMBNAIL, true, false);
            $image->getResizedFileDimensions(ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SIZE_STANDARD, true, false);
            $image->getResizedFileDimensions(ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SIZE_ZOOM, true, false);
        }

        return $image;
    }

    if ($hash) {
        $image->setProductHash($productId);
    } else {
        $image->setProductId($productId);
    }

    // ISC_PRODUCT_IMAGE_SOURCEFILEDOESNTEXIST_EXCEPTION should never really happen at this point with all the checks above so, if it does, let the exception go unhandled to bubble up to a fatal error
    $image->saveToDatabase($generateImages);

    return $image;
}
```

O abaixo carrega a imagem para depois fazer o redimensionamento:

```
public function loadImageFileToScratch()
{
    $filePath = $this->getFilePath();
    $imageType = $this->getImageType();

    // Attempt to increase the memory limit before loading in the image, to ensure it'll fit in memory
    ISC_IMAGE_LIBRARY_FACTORY::setImageFileMemLimit($filePath);

    switch ($imageType) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $this->_scratchResource = @imagecreatefromgif($filePath);
            if ($this->getScratchResource()) {
                imagecolortransparent($this->getScratchResource());
            }
            break;

        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $this->_scratchResource = @imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
            if ($this->_scratchResource) {
                // this sets up alpha transparency support when manipulating and saving the in-memory image
                imagealphablending($this->getScratchResource(), false);
                imagesavealpha($this->getScratchResource(), true);
            }
            break;

        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $this->_scratchResource = @imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath);
            break;

        default:
            throw new ISC_IMAGE_LIBRARY_GD_UNSUPPORTEDIMAGETYPE_EXCEPTION($imageType);
    }

    $this->_updateImageInformation(true);

    if (!$this->getScratchResource()) {
        throw new ISC_IMAGE_LIBRARY_GD_IMAGECREATEFROMFILE_EXCEPTION($imageType, $filePath);
    }
}
```

Depois de carregar a imagem e fazer as alterações necessárias, o script abaixo salva:

```
    public function saveScratchToFile($destinationFilePath, ISC_IMAGE_WRITEOPTIONS $imageWriteOptions)
{
    $imageType = $imageWriteOptions->getImageType();

    switch ($imageType) {

        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            imagejpeg($this->getScratchResource(), $destinationFilePath, (int)$imageWriteOptions->getQuality());
            break;

        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.3', '>=')) {
                // filters parameter was added in 5.1.3
                imagepng($this->getScratchResource(), $destinationFilePath, (int)$imageWriteOptions->getCompression(), (int)$imageWriteOptions->getFilters());
            } else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
                // quality parameter was added in 5.1.2
                imagepng($this->getScratchResource(), $destinationFilePath, (int)$imageWriteOptions->getCompression());
            } else {
                imagepng($this->getScratchResource(), $destinationFilePath);
            }
            break;

        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            imagegif($this->getScratchResource(), $destinationFilePath);
            break;

        default:
            throw new ISC_IMAGE_LIBRARY_GD_UNSUPPORTEDIMAGETYPE_EXCEPTION($imageType);
            break;
    }

    isc_chmod($destinationFilePath, ISC_WRITEABLE_FILE_PERM);
}
```

"getCompression()" está como 0, já tentei deixar com 1, 5 e 9, todos ficaram do mesmo jeito.

"getFilters()" está como "PNG_ALL_FILTERS".

A versão do PHP é maior do que 5.1.3, então ele está usando a primeira opção.

Eu não consigo postar todo o script aqui, pois são vários arquivos para todo o processo de upload/redimensionamento, muitos deles nem fazem parte desse problema. Mas se faltou alguma coisa é só me dizer que eu procuro nos scripts e informo como está.

Esse problema está acontecendo apenas com PNG. JPEG e GIF estão formando imagens limpas e lisas, tanto no "zoom", como no "padrão" e "miniatura".

Existe algum macete para trabalhar com PNG no PHP? Alguma coisa relacionada com o Alpha (eu não trabalho muito com imagens, então não sei o que pode estar acontecendo).

Obrigado.

Comment: Junior, apenas para ter certeza, a imagem PNG que fica serrilhada está sendo mesmo redimensionada e salva em nova dimensão? Veja as propriedades da imagem e verifique as dimensões originais para ver se não está sendo redimensionada pelo HTML, desconheço da GD fazer isso com a imagem, exceto se houver um bug na função de compressão de seu script, valor "0" é sem compressão nenhuma, ou seja, qualidade, e 9 é compressão total, e mesmo assim a compressão PNG da GD muda pouquíssima a qualidade, diferentemente do 'quality' de 0 à 100 para JPG, que deixando "0" fica horrível a imagem.

Comment: @ThyagoThySofT eu nem tinha me tocado nisso, mas depois que você falou eu fui ver a imagem, até fiz o download e realmente ela foi redimensionada.

Comment: Junior, realmente não tinha me deparado com esta situação ainda. Pelo que entendi no código, primeiro é feito o `resize` depois é aplicada a transparência. Se realmente for isso, será que se primeiro realizar o processo com `imagecolorallocatealpha` no tamanho original aplicando a transparência, e depois realizar o resize? Talvez melhore. Testei com fundo branco e não é causado este efeito de serrillha.

Comment: Esquece, não é isso, acabei de testar sua imagem em minha função e não serrilhou como a sua. Vou elaborar uma resposta com base na minha função, ficará mais fácil para adaptar.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Esta resposta realiza o que precisa e com a qualidade que necessita, porém precisará realizar um comparativo e encontrar onde está o problema.
Fica mais difícil encontrar a solução diretamente no seu código pois existem muitos métodos externos e não dá para saber todos os valores que estão sendo passados e como estão sendo passados.

Obs.: O script abaixo é o básico para responder a sua dúvida, não há verificações nem nada de excepcional, está funcional para realizar o teste com a imagem da sua pergunta.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img" />
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Enviar" />
</form>

<?php
if($_POST['ok']) {
    $tempname = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]; // Caminho completo da imagem original.
    $url = "img/nova_imagem.png"; // Caminho onde será salvo a nova imagem e nome do arquivo.
    $max_width = 300; // Largura final da imagem.
    $max_height = 225; // Altura final da imagem.

    move_uploaded_file($tempname, $url); // Move arquivo para servidor.

    // Pega a largura, altura, tipo e atributo da imagem
    list($image_width, $image_height, $type, $attribute) = getimagesize($url);

    // Testa se é preciso redimensionar a imagem
    if(($image_width > $max_width) || ($image_height > $max_height)) {

        if($image_width > $image_height) {
            $new_height = round(($max_width / $image_width) * $image_height);
            $new_width = $max_width;
        }

        if($image_height > $image_width) {
            $new_width = round(($max_height / $image_height) * $image_width);
            $new_height = $max_height;
        }

        if($image_width == $image_height) {
            if($max_width > $max_height) {
                $new_width = round($max_width - ($max_width - $max_height));
                $new_height = $max_height;
            }
            if($max_height > $max_width) {
                $new_height = round($max_height - ($max_height - $max_width));
                $new_width = $max_width;
            }

            if($max_height == $max_width) {
                $new_height = $max_height;
                $new_width = $max_width;
            }
        }

        // Cria uma nova imagem com o novo tamanho  
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

        // Define o background desta nova imagem (RGB), neste caso, 'transparente' como precisa.
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $transparent);
        imagealphablending($new_image, true);
        imagesavealpha($new_image, true);

        $source = imagecreatefrompng($url);
                  imagecopyresampled($new_image, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0,   $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
                  imagepng($new_image, $url, 0); // Compactação '0'

        // Destrói as imagens criadas
        imagedestroy($new_image);
        imagedestroy($source);
    }
}
?>
```

> Precisando testar com imagens de outras dimensões, altere as variáveis `$max_width` e `$max_height` para o valor desejado.

**[UPDATE]**

Resultado Final

[image: Resultado Final]

Comment: Obrigado. Irei tentar rastrear o passo a passo desse script, desde o upload até o redimensionamento, para ver onde e como posso implantar esse script que você passou.

Answer (score 0):

Tente passar o segundo parâmetro de `imagealphablending` como `true`:

```
imagealphablending($image, true);
```

Senão, tente criar uma cor transparente e preencher a imagem com essa cor, antes de fazer a cópia da mesma:

```
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);
imagealphablending($image, true);
```

Vi [nessa resposta do Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620462/why-does-this-transparent-png-cause-borders-when-combined-using-gd).

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu. Continua com o mesmo problema.